# How to leave certain lines out of build using visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to C# and Visual Studio, and this may be a silly question but I do have to find an answer. My question is is it possible to differentiate debug and release builds in such a way the certain lines of code(in my case MessageBox.Show(...)) are compiled if I build under Debug mode, but are left out if I build under Release mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the lines of code in `#if DEBUG` statements:

```
#if DEBUG
    MessageBox.Show("Message");
#endif
```

If you want to do different things in release then you can have:

```
#if DEBUG
    MessageBox.Show("Message");
#else
    // Write to log file
#endif
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the compiler instruction "#if DEBUG" followed by "#endif" so your code will be compiled only on debug mode.

find more details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different conditional compilation symbols in the project's properties (an article [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PreprocessorSymbols.aspx); [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2.aspx) for Visual Studio). Then, using conditional compilation it's easy to include/exclude certain lines. Like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    MessageBox.Show(...);
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `#if DEBUG`, you can also use the `Assert` static method on the `Debug` class in `System.Diagnostics` to check things and show a message box if the value is wrong. e.g:

```
Debug.Assert(IsValid);
```

Will show a message in the debug build if IsValid is false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

```
#if DEBUG
    MessageBox.Show....
#endif
```

If you check build version, you find you have variables defined in project: `DEBUG` is only defined in debug release.
If you want you can also switch the behaviour using

```
#if DEBUG
    MessageBox.Show....
#else
    // do something else here in release mode
#endif
```